# What will be the query in mongo to get all "_id" where "account_type" is equal to "physician"?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I am new in mongo. I want to get "_id" where "account_type" is equal to "physician" from following db. The results will be like: fm26AdxAPQ6rsb8fM, BbgkSPkhYkvoMFaTJ

{ "_id" : "5SH4egqRqRMrvpSxw", "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-09-17T11:27:36.634Z"), "emails" : [ {        "address" : "phys12@gmail.com", "verified" : false } ], "profile" : { "disease_group" : "Heart Patients", "account_type" : "physician" } }

{ "_id" : "fm26AdxAPQ6rsb8fM", "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T08:01:07.339Z"), "emails" : [ { "address" : "newpat@gmail.com", "verified" : false } ], "profile" : { "disease_group" : "Heart Patients", "account_type" : "patient" } }

{ "_id" : "BbgkSPkhYkvoMFaTJ", "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T08:01:52.515Z"), "emails" : [ { "address" : "newpat1@gmail.com", "verified" : false } ], "profile" : { "disease_group" : "Heart Patients", "account_type" : "patient" } }

{ "_id" : "NxBWh2wTvLBbwW4yj", "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T08:03:09.711Z"),"emails" : [ { "address" : "newphy@gmail.com", "verified" : false } ], "profile" : { "disease_group" : "Heart Patients", "account_type" : "physician" } }

Comment: 'The results will be like: fm26AdxAPQ6rsb8fM, BbgkSPkhYkvoMFaTJ' but these ids are belong to "account_type" : "patient"? Could you correct the question please?

Answer (score 1):

To get `"_id"` where `"account_type"` is equal to `"physician"`:

```
db.myCollection.find({"profile.account_type": "physician"}, {"_id":1})
```

Output:

```
5SH4egqRqRMrvpSxw
NxBWh2wTvLBbwW4yj
```